# How to fix 'A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task.'

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

A week ago, I decided to write a Discord bot using c# (discord.net) to function as a GPT Chat via 2 slash commands. However, I faced the "A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task." problem. Here is the code for the bot:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ChatGPT.Net;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.Net;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private CommandService _commands;
    private ChatGpt _chatGpt;
    private bool _isChatting;
    private Queue<string> _messageHistory;
    private List<LogMessage> _logMessages;
    private Dictionary<ulong, List<string>> _userMessageHistory = new Dictionary<ulong, List<string>>();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
        => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    public async Task RunBotAsync()
    {
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        _commands = new CommandService();
        _chatGpt = new ChatGpt("");
        _isChatting = false;
        _messageHistory = new Queue<string>();
        _logMessages = new List<LogMessage>();
        var config = new DiscordSocketConfig
        {
            GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.AllUnprivileged | GatewayIntents.MessageContent
        };
        _client.MessageReceived += MessageReceivedAsync;
        _client.Log += Log;

        await RegisterCommandsAsync();

        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "");
        await _client.StartAsync();

        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }

    private Task Log(LogMessage arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
        _logMessages.Add(arg);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(SocketMessage arg)
    {
        var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
        if (message == null || message.Author.IsBot) return;

        var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

        if (message.Author.IsBot) return;

        if (_isChatting)
        {
            _messageHistory.Enqueue(message.Content);
            string chatInput = string.Join("\n", _messageHistory);

            string chatOutput = await _chatGpt.Ask(chatInput);

            Console.WriteLine($"Пользователь: {message.Content}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Бот: {chatOutput}");

            await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(Format.Bold("Пользователь:") + $" {message.Content}");
            await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(Format.Bold("Бот:") + $" {chatOutput}");

            _messageHistory.Enqueue(chatOutput);
            if (_messageHistory.Count > 3)
            {
                _messageHistory.Dequeue();
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task RegisterCommandsAsync()
    {
        _client.Ready += async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Бот подключен!");

            try
            {
                var startChatCommand = new SlashCommandBuilder()
                    .WithName("startchat")
                    .WithDescription("Начать чат с ChatGPT");
                await _client.CreateGlobalApplicationCommandAsync(startChatCommand.Build());
            }
            catch (ApplicationCommandException exception)
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exception.Errors, Formatting.Indented);
                Console.WriteLine(json);
            }

            try
            {
                var endChatCommand = new SlashCommandBuilder()
                    .WithName("endchat")
                    .WithDescription("Завершить текущий чат с ChatGPT");
                await _client.CreateGlobalApplicationCommandAsync(endChatCommand.Build());
            }
            catch (ApplicationCommandException exception)
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exception.Errors, Formatting.Indented);
                Console.WriteLine(json);
            }
        };

        _client.InteractionCreated += async interaction =>
        {
            if (interaction is SocketSlashCommand slashCommand)
            {
                await SlashCommandHandler(slashCommand);
            }
        };
    }

    private async Task SlashCommandHandler(SocketSlashCommand command)
    {
        var channel = command.Channel;
        switch (command.Data.Name)
        {
            case "startchat":
                await StartChatCommand(command.Data, channel);
                break;
            case "endchat":
                await EndChatCommand(command.Data, channel);
                break;
        }
    }

    private async Task StartChatCommand(SocketSlashCommandData commandData, ISocketMessageChannel channel)
    {
        if (!_isChatting)
        {
            _isChatting = true;
            await channel.SendMessageAsync("Чат начат");
        }
        else
        {
            await channel.SendMessageAsync("Чат уже идет");
        }
    }

    private async Task EndChatCommand(SocketSlashCommandData commandData, ISocketMessageChannel channel)
    {
        var targetId = commandData.Id;

        var message = await channel.GetMessageAsync(targetId) as SocketUserMessage;
        var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

        if (_isChatting)
        {
            _isChatting = false;
            await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Чат окончен");
        }
        else
        {
            await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Чат окончен. Напишите /startchat для начала");
        }

        var userId = message.Author.Id;
        if (_userMessageHistory.ContainsKey(userId))
        {
            var userMessages = _userMessageHistory[userId];
            Console.WriteLine($"История сообщений пользователя {userId}:");
            foreach (var userMessage in userMessages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(userMessage);
            }
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Сохраненные логи:");
        foreach (var logMessage in _logMessages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?
(I'm sorry but I used google translator to write this question)

Comment: By the way, can declare `Main` as `async` with a `Task` return type. Then you don't need that `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` malarkey.

Comment: You cannot execute long running code in gateway event handlers. Anything that takes more than 3 seconds is considered long running as it blocks the gateway.  I would guess that waiting for the response from ChatGPT is your issue. One option would be to wrap the code in an unawaited Task.Run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix it added

```
private Task MessageReceivedAsync(SocketMessage arg)
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
      //...
    });
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).